# Hiding floating action button from other class than MainActivity

Tags: java, android, button

I would like to hide or change the floating action button from an another class but  I couldn't succeed. Can anybody help me out?

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Some onclick action
            }
        });

    }
```

WebAppInterface.java

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        if (toast=="hide") {
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (toast=="change") {
        // update src.Compat command ?
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            // new onclick action
            }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first activity, it's defined before `setContentView`? That would cause the first issue maybe?

Comment: `if (toast.equals("hide")) {
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (toast.equals("change")) {`

Comment: @Mohsen Agree and see the string checking section.

Comment: String.equals() is same as String == String (For Class String)